# Wacom One: device descriptor read/64, error -71

Tags: usb, wacom

Recently I bought a Wacom One (CTL 672/KO-CX). I am having a Lenovo Thinkpad (3yrs old) running Ubuntu 20.04LTS. When I connected it to the laptop, it did not get recognized. I installed drivers from linuxwacom.github.io, but nothing happened. When I run `lsusb`, I don't see Wacom listed there. The tail of `dmesg` looks like:

> ```
> [11517.168074] usb usb1-port2: attempt power cycle
> [11517.824093] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
> [11517.824235] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
> [11518.032224] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
> [11518.240091] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 11, error -71
> [11518.368105] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
> [11518.368245] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
> [11518.576221] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
> [11518.784096] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 12, error -71
> [11518.784130] usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
> [11518.912091] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
> [11519.040097] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
> [11519.276100] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
> [11519.512087] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
> [11519.640103] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
> ```

I need to get his working for teaching purpose. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and I discovered it is a problem related to the newest kernel version (5.4.0-54-generic). For some reason the module is not loaded.
I solved by switching to the next to the last stable version (5.4.0-53-generic).

I hope this helps.